# How to set c# Conditional compilation symbol in Azure Pipeline?

Tags: c#, msbuild, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a c# project containing a Conditional compilation symbol, let's say SYMBOL.

How to set this SYMBOL to true or false in the Azure Pipeline and then run MSBuild with this set?

Can the MSBuild Input Configuration be used, or there are other ways?

Yaml:

```
- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: 'X.csproj'
    platform: 'AnyCPU'
    configuration: 'Release'
    msbuildArguments: '/target:Publish'
    clean: true
    enabled: true
```

It would be great if there is some kind of inputs like "conditionalCompilationSymbol".

Comment: There is a [`DefineConstants`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/language#defineconstants) property defined in the project file. The value of this property will be passed to the C# compiler. Unfortunately, if you pass a property definition for `DefineConstants` on the command line it will not be additive, it will overwrite whatever is already defined for the project. You would modify the yaml `msbuildArguments` to include a [`/p` switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A symbol can be [defined (`#define`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#defining-symbols) but cannot have a value.

There is a [`DefineConstants`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/language#defineconstants) property, the value of which will be passed to the C# compiler. The value of the property is expected to be a semi-colon delimited list of symbols.

A property can be passed to msbuild with the [`/p` switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022).

In the yaml, the `msbuildArguments` would be modified:

```yaml
Yaml:
- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: 'X.csproj'
    platform: 'AnyCPU'
    configuration: 'Release'
    msbuildArguments: '/target:Publish /p:DefineConstants=SYMBOL'
    clean: true
  enabled: true
```

In C# code the conditional compilation block would look like:

```cs
#if SYMBOL
    ...
#endif
```

### Adding to Existing Symbols

Unfortunately, if a project already defines the `DefineConstants` property and a property definition for `DefineConstants` is passed on the command line, the command line value will be used.

Adding to a possible existing set of symbols is not supported out-of-box but is relatively easy to handle.

Create a [`Directory.Build.targets` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-by-directory?view=vs-2022) if one does not already exist. (Don't use the `Directory.Build.props` file. The props file is loaded early before the project defines `DefineConstants`.)

In the `Directory.Build.targets` file add the following `PropertyGroup`:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(DefineAdditionalConstants) != ''">
    <DefineConstants Condition="$(DefineConstants) != ''">$(DefineConstants);$(DefineAdditionalConstants)</DefineConstants>
    <DefineConstants Condition="$(DefineConstants) == ''">$(DefineAdditionalConstants)</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Use `DefineAdditionalConstants` on the command line:

```yaml
Yaml:
- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: 'X.csproj'
    platform: 'AnyCPU'
    configuration: 'Release'
    msbuildArguments: '/target:Publish /p:DefineAdditionalConstants=SYMBOL'
    clean: true
  enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `csproj` file or `DirectoryBuild.props` file you can define the constant based on an MSBuild property

```
<PropertyGorup Condition=" '$(ApplySymbol)' == 'true'">
    <DefineConstants>SYMBOL;$(DefineConstants)</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Whenever the MSBuild property is set, it will *add* SYMBOL to the already defined constants.

```
msbuildArguments: '/target:Publish /p:ApplySymbol=true'
```

To call it from the pipeline you just need to add it as an argument

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `DefineConstants` as property (via [`p` switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022)):

```
msbuildArguments: '/target:Publish /p:DefineConstants="MyValue;DEBUG"'
```